# Can someone help explain the syntax behind this query in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I recently came across this query on Google Sheets and I had a question about one of these queries:

```
=transpose(query(settings!A2:C,"select B, C where A = '" & B4 & "'",0))
```

Could some explain to me this section?

```
= '" & B4 & "'",0)
```

I am struggling to find documentation that can help explain how the ' and " work in Google Sheets queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is creating a query string using a cell value.

Say you had the word Simon in cell B4 then it is constructing

```
"select B, C where A = '" & B4 & "'"
```

as

```
Select B, C where A = 'Simon'
```

The & operator concatenates (combines) strings. Here is is adding the value of cell b4 into your where clause.